# Create an indicator variable for if x happens to y in the future

Tags: r, date, binary, lubridate, tidyverse

I am trying to create a dummy variable in row A based on if rows within 1 year of row A, x occurs. 
I believe this is probably a common issue, and there are similar questions already posted ([this is the most similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020207/how-do-i-do-a-conditional-sum-which-only-looks-between-certain-date-criteria?noredirect=1&lq=1) I found). Unfortunately the zoo package doesn't fit well since it doesn't deal well with [irregular spaced dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556450/rolling-window-over-irregular-time-series) (I don't want to aggregate rows and my data is too large to deal with this well) and I have been trying [unsuccessfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546182/r-sum-by-based-on-date-range) to figure out a datatable way to do this, though I would prefer tidyverse given my experience.

```
dates <- rep(as.Date(c('2015-01-01', '2015-02-02', '2015-03-03', '2016-02-02'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 3)

names <- c(rep('John', 4), rep('Phil', 4), rep('Ty', 4))

df <- data.frame(Name = names, Date = dates,
             did_y = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
             did_x = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))

Name       Date       did_y   did_x
John      2015-01-01    0      1
John      2015-02-02    1      0
John      2015-03-03    1      0
John      2016-02-02    0      0
Phil      2015-01-01    1      0
Phil      2015-02-02    1      1
Phil      2015-03-03    0      1
Phil      2016-02-02    0      0       
Ty        2015-01-01    0      0
Ty        2015-02-02    0      0
Ty        2015-03-03    0      0
Ty        2016-02-02    0      1
```

What I'd like is

```
dffinal <- data.frame(Name = names, Date = dates, 
                  did_y = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                  did_x = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                  did_x_within_year = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                  did_x_next_year = c(0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0, 1, 1, NA))

Name       Date       did_y   did_x   did_x_within_year   did_x_next_year
John      2015-01-01    0      1            1                   0
John      2015-02-02    1      0            1                   0
John      2015-03-03    1      0            1                   0 
John      2016-02-02    0      0            NA                  NA
Phil      2015-01-01    1      0            1                   1
Phil      2015-02-02    1      1            1                   1
Phil      2015-03-03    0      1            1                   0
Phil      2016-02-02    0      0            1                   NA   
Ty        2015-01-01    0      0            0                   0
Ty        2015-02-02    0      0            1                   1
Ty        2015-03-03    0      0            1                   1
Ty        2016-02-02    0      1            1                   NA
```

So I'd like two columns, one for if x occurred within 1 year of row A (regardless of before or after) and another if it occurred within 1 year in the future.

I experimented with RcppRoll, but it seems to only look backward in dates, i.e. if something happened a year before it will dummy, but not if it will occur 1 year in the future.

```
df$did_x_next_year <- roll_max(df$did_x, 365, fill = NA)
```

**EDIT: Attempted solution based on other question**

I have tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549475/how-can-i-roll-up-lagged-time-data-given-conditions-in-a-data-table-in-r/45553386#45553386) (1b), unfortunately nothing in my dataframe/datatable actually changes. Even if I leave the function as is from the example when applied to my data, it does not update.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
df$Year <- lubridate::year(df$Date)
df$Month <- lubridate::month(df$Date)
df$did_x_next_year <- df$did_x

DT <- as.data.table(df)

k <- 12 # prior 12 months

# inputs zoo object x, subsets it to specified window and sums
Max2 <- function(x) {
  w <- window(x, start = end(x) - k/12, end = end(x) - 1/12)
  if (length(w) == 0 || all(is.na(w))) NA_real_ else max(w, na.rm = TRUE)
}

nms <- names(DT)[7]

setkey(DT, Name, Year, Month) # sort

# create zoo object from arguments and run rollapplyr using Sum2
roll2 <- function(x, year, month) {
  z <- zoo(x, as.yearmon(year + (month - 1)/12))
  coredata(rollapplyr(z, k+1, Max2, coredata = FALSE, partial = TRUE))
}

DT <- DT[, nms := lapply(.SD, roll2, Year, Month), .SDcols = nms, by = "Name"]
```

Comment: row A means row 1??

Comment: Well I am grouping the data based on the Name column and I am looking for the time window to roll forward with each row so the calculation would be done look forward and backward from the date of each row.

Comment: So you want a rolling mean or interpolate?

Comment: Sorry if I am missing your meaning, but I am trying to 1. group by Name, 2. for each row then look forward from the date of the row to all subsequent rows within a year, 3. if in those subsequent rows, did_x = 1, then to give the did_x_within_year = 1

Comment: in `did_x_within_year` `Name=Ty` should it be 0 rather than 1  ?

Comment: @Wen, well I'm counting the date up to a year so I'm including the edge case.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549475/how-can-i-roll-up-lagged-time-data-given-conditions-in-a-data-table-in-r/45553386#45553386

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck, I'm very new to data.table and zoo so trying to parse that other answer together. I wonder if there is a tidyverse solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a suggestion from a friend, I came up with the following:

```
# Filtering to the obs I care about
dfadd <- df %>% filter(did_x == 1) %>% select(Name, Date) %>% rename(x_date = Date)

# Converting to character since in dcast it screws up the dates
dfadd$x_date <- as.character(dfadd$x_date)

# Merging data
df <- plyr::join(df, dfadd, by = 'Name')

# Creating new column used for dcasting
df <- df %>% group_by(Name, Date) %>% mutate(x_date_index = seq(from = 1, to = n()))
df$x_date_index <- paste0('x_date_',df$x_date_index)

#casting the data wide
df <- reshape2::dcast(df,
                  Name + Date + did_y + did_x ~ x_date_index,
                  value.var = "x_date",
                  fill = NA)

# Converting to back to date
df$x_date_1 <- as.Date(df$x_date_1)
df$x_date_2 <- as.Date(df$x_date_2)

# Creating dummy variables
df$did_x_within_year <- 0
df$did_x_within_year <- ifelse((df$x_date_1 - df$Date) <= 366, 1, 
df$did_x_within_year)

df$did_x_next_year <- 0
df$did_x_next_year <- ifelse(((df$x_date_1 > df$Date) & (df$x_date_1 - df$Date<= 365)), 
                         1, df$did_x_next_year)

# Can extend to account for x_date_2, x_date_3, etc

# Changing the last entry to NA as desired
df <- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(did_x_next_year = c(did_x_next_year[-n()], NA))
```